# Best practice validating object

Tags: java, validation

I want to validate that an object validates some rules, but I'm not sure what's the best way to do it. I've a Validator class to validate some objects.

Any recommendations?

Comment: there is no other way as i see it, you need to make 1 or 2 validate methods and check for each variable seperately. what you want to do is so specific that it cant be done in another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have broadly two ways :

- specifying the validation constraints directly on the fields on the classes.
  [The bean validation API](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) may help you.
  `@NotEmpty`, `@NotBlank`, ... are constraints that should interest you.
  You may find example of this API [here](http://hibernate.org/validator/).
- defining a class as you did that performs the overall validation of an object generally passed as parameter of a method of this validation class.
  The bean validation API may still interest you.

Each way has its advantages and its limitations.
You should be aware of them and use the way that matches better to your requirement.
Here is a little summary fast cooked. I miss probably some things but I think that it could give you some insights/ideas.

**Specifying constraints on the fields**

Advantages :

- constraints hold by the classes to validate themselves : code more meaningful.
- constraints reusable if these are not specific to a use case.

Limitations :

- if you have multiples ways to validate the constraints, it will not be enough.
- the validation may be exploded in multiple classes : harder to read/maintain code.

Example : validating JPA entities by specifying constraints on entity classes themselves makes sense : you have one way to validate each bean (according to the data model) and you want to reuse these validations.

**Defining a validator class**

Advantages :

- extensible model : allows multiple ways to validate the object constraints : just create a new validator
- single place to read/maintain validation code.
- don't need to change the classes to validate themselves (sometimes you cannot or don't want)

Limitations :

- constraints not reusable even if the constraints are not specific to a use case. 
  You have to create a new validator class for each case.

Example : validating user requests according to their profile by using  validator classes makes sense : you may have different rules according to the user profile and you want also to separate them in specific validator class to ease their maintenance/readability.

Comment: Sometimes I also like to add a `Validatable` interface to my classes which offers a `validate()` method. And then I have some other place where I make sure to run this method for every created object that is `Validatable`. For example when creating objects automatically through GSON. So the classes are then validating themselves, if someone triggers the method.